# How to get custom http status text for ios using j2objc

Tags: j2objc

I'm using `HttpURLConnection.getResponseMessage()` to get http status text. When the server responses with custom status text like `HTTP/1.1 500 ItemNotFoundException`, translated to objective c method returns standard message for status code 500 - `Internal Server Error`. Original java method returns `ItemNotFoundException`.

Will it be fixed in future releases?

Answer (score 0):

[Please file an issue](https://github.com/google/j2objc/issues/new), with either a public URL that demonstrates this issue, or example code that's failing. While unit tests are ideal, most developers attach a simple Java command-line class ([like HelloWorld](https://developers.google.com/j2objc/guides/getting-started)) that succeeds using the JVM and fails after being translated into a macOS binary.